# How to ingore tslint.json file in angular2 of another project?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, lint, package.json

I have an angular app which has another standalone angular app as a dependency. Everything works fine apart from the linting.

The problem is when I run **ng lint** in my terminal I get the following error:

> Failed to load path.... node/modules/codelyzer.

When I remove my *tslint.json* from the dependency project the error resolves immediately.

The problem is here obviously that angular sees two *tslint.json*, one from my main app and the other from the dependency project which is now part of the main app.

How can I solve this problem without manually deleting the *tslint.json* from the dependency project? I would like to keep it there.

I was thinking about excluding it in the *angular.cli.json* lint field, but wasn't successful. Also put an exclude in the tslint.json but didn't get positive results

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, I've excluded tslint.json from my main app in the angular.cli.json
by writing the following:

```
"lint": [
  {
  "project": "path/tslint.json",
  "exclude": "path/node_modules/my_project"
  }
]
```